# Get email type inside email template - order emails

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there a way of getting the email type (New Order, Cancelled Order etc) inside the Woocommerce order email template files?

e.g. in `email-header.php` I'd like to do this (pseudo code):

```
if(email type is 'new order')
    echo 'Hey admin, this is a new order';
elseif(email type is 'order processing')
    echo 'Hey customer, here is some custom info I wanted to add to this email';
```

Comment: Why don't you add your code to the according email templates e.g. customer-processing-order.php?